# match multiple words instead of a single word

Tags: c#, regex

i have the following regex:

```
private string tokenRegEx = @"\[%RC:(\w+)%\].*?";
```

which is when i pass in the string below it finds it:

```
[%RC:TEST%]
```

However the following returns false

```
[%RC:TEST ITEM%]
```

how can i modify the regex to allow for spaces as well as whole words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the `\w` pattern (which matches alphanum plus underscore only) to something more liberal. For example this would also allow whitespace:

```
private string tokenRegEx = @"\[%RC:((\w|\s)+)%\].*?";
```

Of course the "correct" solution would need to take into account exactly what you consider acceptable input, which is kind of open to discussion at this point.

Comment: Thank you very much.  as soon as i am allowed to accept answer i will :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@"\[%RC:(\w|\s)+%\].*?";
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do it, you have to match a space too. You use a group `()` but using a set `[]` is less expensive

```
private string tokenRegEx = @"\[%RC:([ \w]+)%\].*?";
```